# I can't figure out __main__ == __name__

Tags: python, windows

Good time of day. I would like to know about `__main__` and `__name__`. Let's say I have a main file and a second file. If I import a function from the main file into the second one, and run the second file, does it stop being `__main__`?

I tried to run the main file after I imported the function from it, and in it `__main__ == __name__` could you explain to me why this is happening? And one more question, did I understand correctly that it is not worth importing anything from the main file?

Comment: It's `"__main__"`, not `__main__` (note the `"`). It's an important difference as `__main__` is undefined variable and will raise an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing from another file, `__name__` would be *the file's* name (not `'__main__`).

The steps are:

1. run a python file
2. the file imports a function which contains a `__name__== '__main__'` construction from `function_file.py` as `from fuction_file import func`
3. you get the following output:

function_file.py

```py
def func():
    print('Function call from another file')
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print(f"""Entered `__name__ == '__main__'` block""")
    else:
        print(f"""Could not enter `__name__ != '__main__'` block""")
        print(f"""__name__ = '{__name__}'""")
```

Output:

```bash
>>> Function call from another file
>>> Could not enter `__name__ != '__main__'` block
>>> __name__ = 'function_file'
```